# Import TSV file into hbase table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm using hortonworks 2.1 with hbase and hive.
I want to create a hbase table from tsv file. The file is here:

```
  id    c1  c2
row1    1   22
row2    e1  42
row3    g1  f2
row4    f1  c2
row5    d1  c2
row6    c1  42
row7    e1  c2
row8    c1  c2
row9    c1  c2
row10   c1  22
```

The command I used is:

```
bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns= HBASE_ROW_KEY,d:c1,d:c2 hbaseTable /tmp/testTSV.tsv
```

But I got this error:

```
SyntaxError: (hbase):5: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG
```

this is the error:

```
hbase(main):007:0> ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns= HBASE_ROW_KEY,d:c1,d:c2 hbaseTable/tmp/testTSV.tsv
SyntaxError: (hbase):7: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG

ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns= HBASE_ROW_KEY,d:c1,d:c2 hbaseTable /tmp/testTSV.tsv
                                              ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a table already created in Hbase ? You will first have to create a table in Hbase with 'd' as a column family and then you can import this tsv file into that table.

Answer (score 0):

After creating the table, the import command dont execute in hbase shell, you can execute in normal console then it will work properly
let us below example

1. create the tabls in hbase shell as per our requirement

   ```
   create 'mytable5', 'cf'
   create 'mytable6', 'cf'
   ```
2. keep the data in hdfs

   ```
   hadoop fs -put /home/mani/work/hbase_inputs /hbase_inputs
   ```
3. import command execute in normal console

   ```
   hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf:c1,cf:c2 mytable5 hdfs://localhost:8020/hbase_inputs/import/sample1.tsv
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud create a table in Hbase with 'd' as a column family and then you can import this tsv file into that table.

Comment: How is your answer different from [existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27291971/8036431)?