# Loading Json Data to hbase using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, hbase, apache-spark-sql

i wanted to load data into a Hbase Table using pyspark,
Can some one help how to load the json data to Hbase as ticid as rowkey as and all other goes into one column family.
Please find the json below.

{
    "ticid": "1496",
    "ticlocation": "vizag",
    "custnum": "222",
    "Comments": {
        "comment": [{
            "commentno": "1",
            "desc": "journey",
            "passengerseat": {
                "intele": "09"
            },
            "passengerloc": {
                "intele": "s15"
            }
        }, {
            "commentno": "5",
            "desc": " food",
            "passengerseat": {
                "intele": "09"
            },
            "passengerloc": {
                "intele": "s15"
            }
        }, {
            "commentno": "12",
            "desc": " service",
            "passengerseat": {
                "intele": "09"
            },
            "passengerloc": {
                "intele": "s15"
            }
        }]
    },
    "Rails": {
        "Rail": [{
            "Traino": "AP1545",
            "startcity": "vizag",
            "passengerseat": "5"
        }, {
            "Traino": "AP1555",
            "startcity": "HYD",
            "passengerseat": "15A"
        }]
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't have a single row to load but thousands or millions of rows? I would recommend converting your JSON data to TSV (tab separated) which is quite easy in Python and using the **import-tsv** feature of HBase 
See also
[Import TSV file into hbase table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291656/import-tsv-file-into-hbase-table)

Spark is not a good pattern for HBase Bulk load.