# How to load csv file from hdfs to hbase table using Dimporttsv

Tags: shell, csv, hdfs, hbase

I am trying to load csv file into an hbase table using shell command `Dimporttsv.`
The csv files reside in a dir in my hdfs (/csvFiles)

the csv file was generated from a mysql table with the following feilds:

```
+-------------+
Field       
+-------------+
tweet_id
user_id
screen_name
description
created_at
+-------------+
```

I created a table in hbase with a single family name as shown below:

```
create 'dummyTable', 'cf1'
```

the command I am using:

```
ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=',' -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf1:user_id,cf1:tweet_id,cf1:screen_name,cf1:description,cf1:created_at dummyTable /csvFiles/all_users.csv
```

however I am getting this syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: (hbase):8: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG
```

I've looked at the following posts and followed the recommendations in them but to no avail. I would appreciate your help.

[Import TSV file into hbase table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291656/import-tsv-file-into-hbase-table)

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/4942/import-csv-data-into-hbase-using-importtsv.html

http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#importtsv

Answer (score 0):

Exit from `Hbase shell` and try by adding single quotes to `importtsv.columns`

```
bash$ hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=',' -Dimporttsv.columns='HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf1:user_id,cf1:tweet_id,cf1:screen_name,cf1:description,cf1:created_at' dummyTable hdfs://<your_name_node_addr>/csvFiles/all_users.csv
```

(or)

**`From Hbase Shell:`**

```
hbase(main):001:0> ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=',' -Dimporttsv.columns='HBASE_ROW_KEY,cf1:user_id,cf1:tweet_id,cf1:screen_name,cf1:description,cf1:created_at' dummyTable hdfs://<your_name_node_addr>/csvFiles/all_users.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used dfs.namenode.rpc-address and port from ```/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml```  but got path does not exist.

Comment: if your file is in `local path` then dont need to add `hdfs://<your_name_node_addr>` full hdfs file path. just keep your local file path like **`/csvFiles/all_users.csv`** and try to execute the commands again please..!!